# How can I get link text from CSS to string object?

Tags: javascript, css, web-scraping

I have HTML tag with link in background style and I want this link to be a string in my JS file. How can I do that?

```
<div class="bmlistt" style="background: url('b.ppy.sh/thumb/845746.jpg';)"></div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you have?

Comment: You will first have to fix the typo(?): `url('b.ppy.sh/thumb/845746.jpg';)` -> `url('b.ppy.sh/thumb/845746.jpg')`

Comment: That's not a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the it using this:

```
var bg = $("div.bmlistt").css('background');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
```

Comment: The question is tagged `javascript` not `jquery` (or any other library)

Comment: Yes but its online page which Im scrapping. What about it?

Comment: @Andreas I missed the `JavaScript` tag and posted a solution. If @kjoszi can use `Jquery` in your page then my solution is perfectly fine else you can refer to other solutions posted.

Comment: That's not my page. Im scrapping online page ;/

Comment: That's totally fine. But the environment you are scrapping the page, does that support jquery?

Comment: its cheeriojs and yes it supports it

Comment: Then you can use it and it'll work. Please add this and test whether you are able to parse url's or not.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9HdeAN2t  it works on https://jsfiddle.net but in console i got error: var styles = parse(el.attribs.style);
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribs' of undefined

with your solution same issue

Answer (score 0):

No need for big libraries. `querySelector` to get the div. I would use its `style.background` or `style.backgroundImage` property. The latter of those only contains the image itself, and not any other background css you might specify in a real life scenario, possibly making it easier to extract the url.

Unfortunately with your specific HTML that doesn't work, because of an error in the CSS (the semicolon). So in that case you have to parse the `style` *attribute* as text, rather than relying on the style object *property*, which contains the browser's interpretation of your CSS. Both solutions are shown below.

```js
var theDiv = document.querySelector('.bmlistt');
console.log(theDiv.style);

// Doesn't work because of error in the CSS. Otherwize this would do it.
var css = theDiv.style.backgroundImage;
console.log(css.substr(5, css.length - 7));

var attr = theDiv.getAttribute('style');
// This, if you know the length of the 'overhead' around the url, or
// a regular expression.
console.log(attr.substr(17, attr.length - 20));
```

```html
<div class="bmlistt" style="background: url('b.ppy.sh/thumb/845746.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: @Andreas I did test it, but I admit I fixed the syntax error in the CSS first. backgroundImage, because that's how the browser (at least Chrome) stores this property. You can inspect the style object by itself and see exactly which properties are populated. For a real life scenario, that property seems best, because it would not return any other background properties you set..  But since I don't know the actual scenatio, I also added an alternative to get the url straight from the style attribute, in case OP would have to deal with HTML that actually contains this syntax error.

Comment: In Chromium based browser `background` would also work. But it won't with Firefox because Firefox adds all the other properties to the content: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(\"b.ppy.sh/thumb/845746.jpg\") repeat scroll 0% 0%` ([Example](https://jsbin.com/rageceqeqe/edit?html,js,console))

Comment: So, better use `backgroundImage` then, or the style attribute itself, if you can't get rid of the typo.

Comment: Yes but its online page which Im scrapping. What about it?

Comment: Yes, what about it?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```js
const imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName('bmlistt')[0];
let image = imageElement.style.background.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');

console.log(image);
```

```html
<div class="bmlistt" style="background: url(b.ppy.sh/thumb/845746.jpg)"></div> <!-- Fix ";" in style attribute -->
```

Comment: Yes but its online page which Im scrapping. What about it?

Comment: Im scrapping web page to get information about it and I want to get scrapped link from this webpage style tag.

Comment: @kjoszi you should add that in the question. For scraping webpages I think it's easier to use python